# Problema con una API

Tags: html, css, reactjs, api

Tengo un problema con el código en el que estoy trabajando para una pagina web.

Quiero editar un producto que ya ha sido cargado anteriormente, trabajo con el formulario que uso para cargar este mismo producto y hago un llamado a la `api`.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
   const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/products/update-product`, 
   formData)
   console.log('Producto actualizado:', response.data);
   navigate(`/product/${params.id}`);
 } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating product:', error);
    console.log(error.response); // Muestra el error completo en la consola
```

}
};

La api es la misma que utilizo en el form de `addProduct`, y la correcta desde la base de datos. En la consola me muestra un error de

> " Error updating product: AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …} "

No entiendo que puede estar fallando. Un dato a agregar es que, el llamado a la `api` anterior que realizo para traer la información que este producto contiene, lo realiza bien, el problema es a la hora de actualizar una categoría, nombre o lo que se quiera actualizar.

Probe verificando la API con Postman, pero funciona correctamente, entonces ¡hay algo mal en mi código!

Comment: ¿En el postman verificaste si es `http` o `https` ?

Answer (score 0):

Si con postman esta actualizando correctamente entonces toma en cuenta el tipo de dato que estas enviando y recibiendo en la Api.

toma como ejemplo la petición de entrada de datos ya que el proceso de suministro de datos a la base de datos es similar al proceso de actualización de datos.

debes hacer varias pruebas hacia cada endpoint, utiliza el metodo POS para facilitar las pruebas.